# How to Implement search method for db records with multiple filters using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to implement a Search method with multiple filters on db records.

The below code works fine but when ever one of the filters is `null` a:

> NullReferenceException

...occurs

```
var user = model.Username != null ? await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username) : null;
res = DB.UserWatchActivityLogs.Where(x => x.User_Id == (user != null ? user.Id : x.User_Id) &&
x.Tutorial.Title.Contains(model.TutorialName ?? "") &&
x.DateTime >= (model.DateTimeFrom != null ? DateTime.Parse(model.DateTimeFrom, new CultureInfo("fa-IR")) : x.DateTime) &&
x.DateTime <= (model.DateTimeTo != null ? DateTime.Parse(model.DateTimeTo, new CultureInfo("fa-IR")) : x.DateTime))
        .Include(x => x.User).Include(x => x.Tutorial).ToList();
```

Comment: Is user.Id or x.User_Id equal to null?

Answer (score 1):

Linq deferrs the execution of the query until the result is materialised.  This happens when the collection is iterated over or `ToList()` is called on the result.

You can chain together linq queries until you want to materialise the result set. Check whether the filter is `null` before applying it to your query.

See below for an idea, hopefully you'll be able to adapt it to your needs:

```
var user = model.Username != null ? await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username) : null;

var res = DB.UserWatchActivityLogs.Include(x => x.User).Include(x => x.Tutorial);

// filter by Id if user is not null
if (user != null)
{
    res = res.Where(x => x.User_Id == user.Id);
}

// filter by tutorial name if it is not null
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.TutorialName))
{
    res = res.Where(x => x.Tutorial.Title.Contains(model.TutorialName);
}

// filter by date from (assuming model.DateTimeFrom is a string)
if (DateTime.TryParse(model.DateTimeFrom, new CultureInfo("fa-IR"), DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dateFrom))
{
    res = res.Where(x.DateTime >= dateFrom);
}

if (DateTime.TryParse(model.DateTimeTo, new CultureInfo("fa-IR"), DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dateTo))
{
    res = res.Where(x.DateTime <= dateTo);
}

// materialise the results in a list, this is when the query is executed
var results = res.ToList();
```

Here I've assumed `model.DateTimeTo` and `model.DateTimeFrom` are string so you could try to parse it to DateTime before filtering.